# Grafana specific data export as csv

Tags: prometheus, grafana, victoriametrics

## Grafana Export Format

By exporting huge amounts of time series data i get the first column of my csv file in the following format: "2023-09-08 09:39:00". Can i somehow seperate YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM:SS into seperate columns before exporting? Thanks in advance. Btw. Using a Prometheus-Backend for the time series data

I tried using transformations, you can apply them before export.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is presented on the Table, you'll need to duplicate your Time column, and apply different Format Time transformations to them.\

Example how it can be done:

1. Apply transformation **Add field from calculation**, Mode *Binary operation*, Operation `Time + 0`, Alias *Date*.
2. Apply transformation **Convert field type** to field *Date*, a *Time*
3. Apply transformation **Format Time** to field *Time* with format `HH:mm:ss`
4. Apply transformation **Format Time** to field *Date* with format `YYYY-MM-DD`

If your data is presented on other panels, that will not work after time field duplication, I think you cannot do what you described. The easiest way in this case will be to split date column on the CSVs side. This can be achieved in various ways: manual in client application (Excel and alike), programmatically in said client app with things like macros, or programmatically modify file using any programming language.